# Can't get apple llvm 4.1 compiler options to show up in xcode 4.5, only llvm gcc 4.2

Tags: xcode, objective-c++, xcode4.5

On most projects, If I change the compiler I'm using from "apple llvm compiler 4.1" to "llvm gcc 4.2", the compiler options available later on in Build settings will change accordingly.

Right now, I'm doing a project using objective-c++ , but I'm noticing the compiler options don't update (see screenshot below). Anyone ever experienced this? Is there a way to fix this without creating a brand new project?

I was trying to switch to the apple llvm compiler to try using ARC (and yes, I've read http://philjordan.eu/article/mixing-objective-c-c++-and-objective-c++ and it's recommendation to not use ARC in this scenario).

NOTE: I'm using Xcode Version 4.5 (4G182)

[image: compiler set to apple llvm compiler, but settings are still stuck on llvm gcc 4.2]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it by editing my project.pbxproj file using a text editor. I had inconsistent settings of "GCC_VERSION" in the file. I quit Xcode and then simply deleted all the lines with GCC_VERSION in them. Restarted Xcode and suddenly I got the default compiler (apple llvm) and all the appropriate compiler options.

Answer (score 0):

Click the "All" label on the top gray bar, and all the options will show up:

[image]